# USB drive with password write protection

Tags: usb, encryption

I'm looking for a **password-write-protected USB Drive** or Flash Memory card where I can write to it only with a password.
Do such products exist?

I DO NOT want a software protection/encryption with a common pendrive, I need a suitable drive for this purpose with some specific hardware features. And maybe I will need a custom native library to write to it.

(Mandatory) Requirements:

- No encryption required
- 512MB or more storage
- Write password protection

Optional Requirements:

- Write via native means of the OS or via specialized library
- Read without password, possibly like a common usb pendrive.

Password method is not mandatory but I must be sure that only my software should toggle write protection on/off. So any other method is welcome, for example an hardware switch is not good because everybody could turn it on or off.

Comment: Do you actually need the password or would a simple write-lock toggle solve the issue you are having?

Comment: Password method is not mandatory but I must be sure that only my software should toggle write protection on/off. So any other method is welcome, for example an hardware switch is not good because everybody could turn it on or off.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered biometric USB drives, such as the Imation Defender F200 Biometric, it may be a little slow, but supports passwords, fingerprint scanning, or both. There is a review of it: [Imation Defender F200 Biometric Flash Drive Review: Secure but Slow](http://www.pcworld.com/article/254757/imation_defender_f200_biometric_flash_drive_review_secure_but_slow.html).

Or there is the Iron Key Personal D200, which does not specifically have a password enabled write protect, but it is pretty damn secure, nevertheless. Here is a, somewhat out of date, review: [IronKey Personal D200](http://secure-usb-drive-review.toptenreviews.com/ironkey-personal-d200-review.html).

---

As an aside, have you seen [George Bailey](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/764/george-bailey)'s [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15219/is-there-such-thing-as-a-password-enforced-write-protected-flash-drive#answer-15635) to [Is there such thing as a password enforced write protected flash drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15219/is-there-such-thing-as-a-password-enforced-write-protected-flash-drive):

> (The write protect switch on the model drive I have used is discrete like a reset button, you need to stick a pen or something into the slot in order to reach the switch and flip it)
>
> The best solution I have so far - that still satisfies the requirement that no malicious files be downloaded by the user - is to get a flash drive that has a physical write protect switch, and apply a coating that will harden. (similar coats are on the market for covering tool handles, such as wrenches)
>
> If the hacker has physical access, I see this setup as having 2 possible outcomes
>
> - the tamper would be evident to the user (broken seal), or
> - after tamper is complete, a new coat of similar color would have to be applied by the hacker.

Again while not password protected, it does get around the issue that you mention in your comment *hardware switch is not good because everybody could turn it on or off*.

Comment: I have to freely write to this decive, the protection is necessary to avoid the erase/overwrite. I cannot use hardware switch because I cannot be sure that someone switch it erase something and switch it again. I'm looking for an hardware protection by password that can be switch only via API with a password. This way I can use a custom middleware (the only password keeper) to write: it switchs to write mode the drive, check if the file already exists and this case thrown an exception, otherwise goes on and finally switch the drive to readonly.